# Video preview screen freezes UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UIImagePickerController` to allow user to pick video from media library. When a video is selected and while it is being compressed, if the device gets locked and when I unlock the device, Media URL is absent in the info dictionary.

I do nothing(don't even dismiss the Image picker) when the media url is absent. The controls on the preview screen don't work so that user can reselect the video.
Code I used is:

```
self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.movie", @"public.image", nil];
[self.imagePicker setDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Why do controls don't work? How can I make them work?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement the two delegate method:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject])
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
```

Comment: Already doing it...in cases where media url is absent I do not dismiss the picker, so that user can select the media again.

Answer (score 0):

didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo wont call until user select video. u can dismiss picker where safely